# Kentico one domain with multiple cultures

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, kentico

Using Kentico 8.1 for a multilingual site.

Each culture has one domain except for one domain that needs to show 2 cultures.

I have enabled: **Force domain culture**

Under domain Aliases I have set domain.ca to french, but it needs to be able to show both: French -Canada and English- Canada.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about one website... it must be translated into both cultures of course.

Then you will simply configure preferred culture for every domain and then on the master page you will place **web part -> Language selector** and in the **visibility property** of this web part you will use macro to check the current domain and if the current domain name will be "domain.ca" you will return true, so the language selector will be visible, otherwise it will be hidden for all other domains.

-> Other domains will be displayed only in preferred culture.